# Find the smallest integer I which when represented as float is such that I+1=I

Tags: floating-point

So I had a question which asked me to find the smallest integer I  which is such that when it is represented as a float, `I+1=I`

I wrote a simple C++ program for it and it worked fine.

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    float i=1;
    while(1<2)
    {
        if(i+1==i)
            {cout << fixed << i << endl;
                break;}
        i=i+1;
    }


}
```

However, when I try to run it with the condition `I+2==I`, it does not work. It neither shows me any error nor does the program end. I just get a blank screen.

Why is it so?

Initially I thought that it is probably because the computer is taking too much time to execute it. But the answer is approximately 2 times of what we get when we use the condition `I+1==I`. So for instance the original program took 1s, the `I+2==I` program should take at most 2s. So time should not be a problem.

Comment: It is considered extremely rude to edit a question in a way that invalidates existing answers. It wastes time of the answerers, whose answer is now useless. It wastes time of readers who wonder why the answer doesn't answer the question. It will lead to the answer getting downvoted because it doesn't answer the question. Please, consider rolling back your edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `i` is big enough for `i+1==i`, your loop will stop incrementing `i`. That will happen before `i+2==i`.

Answer (score 0):

The only `i` for which the equality `i + 2 == 2` holds true is `i = 0`. If you start with `i = 1` and count upwards, you will never reach `0`.

Comment: I'm sorry. It was 'I+2==I'. I have edited the question